# $http interceptor, change header

Tags: angularjs

I have acces token, send in header.

```
 $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: 'someUrl',
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + userService.access_token
                }
            });
        },
```

On access, token expiration, server returns 403.
I already have interceptor that asking for new token.

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
      //getting new access token
      //need to change header for new acces_token, before resending
      $injector('$http').(rejection.config);
      return //somePromise;
    }
```

Is it possible to modify rejection.config header, inject new access token to header, then resend modified request?